# Uploading images from Google Drive to Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a collection named places at firebase fire store and one of its fields is photos which is an string contains all photos links seperated by `","` and some docs contain only one photo so it doesn't contain `","` I want to get each place photos and upload it to my firebase storage that is the code that I been able to reach it

```
Future<void> uploadImages() async {
  CollectionReference placesReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("places");
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> placesJsonList = [];
  var place;
  var places = await placesReference.get();
  places.docs.forEach((element) {
    place = element.data();
    place['id'] = element.id;
    placesJsonList.add(place);
  });

  if (placesJsonList.length != 0) {
    List<PlacesModel> placesJsonListToPlacesModel = placesJsonList
        .map<PlacesModel>(
            (jsonPlaceModel) => PlacesModel.fromJson(jsonPlaceModel))
        .toList();

    for (int i = 0; i < placesJsonListToPlacesModel.length; i++) {
      String? photosUrl = placesJsonListToPlacesModel[i].photos;
      if (photosUrl != null) {
        if (photosUrl.contains(",")) {
          List<String>? photoUrls = photosUrl.split(",");
          print("Photos urls loop");
          print(photoUrls.length);
          for (String photoUrl in photoUrls) {
            photoUrl = photoUrl.trim();
            http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(photoUrl));
            String filename = path.basename(photoUrl);

            Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
                .ref('places/${placesJsonListToPlacesModel[i].id}/photos/$filename');
            await ref.putData(response.bodyBytes);
          }
        } else {
          print("Enter else statement");
          http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(photosUrl));
          String filename = path.basename(photosUrl);

          Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref('places/${placesJsonListToPlacesModel[i].id}/photos/$filename');
          await ref.putData(response.bodyBytes);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that photos are uploaded like that:
[Firebase Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPg7v.png)
[FireStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blre6.png)

It seems like it is the Google Drive photo ID not the photo itself

How can I be able to upload it as JPEG image?